# C# graphics draw transparent rectangle over area

Tags: c#, graphics

I have two images layered ontop of each other and want to be able to clear a section of the top image. Normally if I wanted to clear a section of an image I would just paint it the background color by doing

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,x,y,width,height);
```

but if I do that on the top image that area of the bottom image gets covered by the white rectangle. I tried doing

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent,x,y,width,height);
```

but that does not seem to clear the region of all of it's previous contents. Is there any way I can make the pixels in that region transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

GDI+ and the `Graphics` class do not support layered drawing; once you overwrite the previous image, those pixels are *gone*.

You should re-draw the portion of the previous image that you want to appear by calling a `DrawImage` overload that takes two rectangles.

If the lower image contains transparent portions, you should first clear that area to white (or whatever your original background is) by calling `FillRectangle` so that the transparency is overlaid correctly.

Answer (score 5):

```
//using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,x,y,width,height);
g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;    
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent,x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: This does not work, CompositingMode.SourceCopy only affects the RGB channels.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Another option is not to paint the images directly. Use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
```

and it's property

```
Region
```

to change the visibility/transaparency of the image. Region need not to be rectangle. It may be defined from any set of lines.

PS: `Brushes.Transparent` doesn't really mean transparent, but BackColor of the parent container.

Comment: Your `PS` is only true when painting on controls.  Bitmaps support full alpha-blended transparency.  However, `Transparent` means "do nothing"; it doesn't mean "erase pixels".

Answer (score 0):

```
float[][] ptsArray ={
            new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0.5f, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
            ColorMatrix clrMatrix = new ColorMatrix(ptsArray);
            ImageAttributes imgAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
            imgAttributes.SetColorMatrix(clrMatrix,
            ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
            ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            _ImageThumb.Height, imgAttributes);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_ImageThumb,new Rectangle(0, 0, _ImageThumb.Width,_ImageThumb.Height),0, 0, _ImageThumb.Width, _ImageThumb.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttributes);
```

//use set clip & region to draw